Home/End key on external keyboard not working in certain apps
I have an external keyboard (Logitech G910, if that's relevant). I wanted to make the Home and End keys work, so I followed this guide https://www.starryhope.com/mac/mac-os-x-home-and-end-keys/
The Home and End keys now do work, but only in some Apps. It works in Firefox, Safari, Sublime Text, VS Code but they do not work in Terminal and Mathematica. What how can I make the keys work in other apps as well?
Ideally I'd prefer not downloading another application.
The above mentioned link suggests adding the following to ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBindings.dict
{
        /* Remap Home / End to be correct  */
        "\\UF729"  = "moveToBeginningOfLine:"; 
        "\\UF72B"  = "moveToEndOfLine:";
        "$\\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:"; 
        "$\\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:"; 
}


It’s not practical to send us off site to read a guide to figure out what you did.  Please summarize your steps here with an [edit]

@Allan added a brief description.

There seems to be a distinction between "moveToLeftEndOfLine" and "moveToBeginningOfLine". Swapping in the former fixed the issue in Mathematica at least, but not in terminal. But to be completely fair, Cmd+Left doesn't work in terminal either.

This is a common misunderstanding.  Terminal.app is not responsible for those keystrokes, the shell you are running is.  If you are using bash, configure your keybindings in ~/.inputrc.  If you are using zsh, configure them in zle, the zsh command line editor(man zshzle).
